# angularjs ng-bind-html to iframe is rendering HTML outside of <html> tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I am loading a page from $http.get into an iFrame.  The $http.get retrieves the full HTML page as if it were natively navigated to, but when I am attaching the content to the iframe, the content is getting loaded outside of the HTML tags...and the original HTML tags in the retrieved document are now missing.

Controller:

```
  // call to $http.get() service
  clubService.eventShow($scope.club.ceID)
  .then(function(res) {
    if (res.success == true) {
      $scope.eventItem.urlHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(res.data);
      $scope.eventItem.isLogin = 1 ;        
    }
  }) ;
```

HTML:

```
  <iframe id="eventFrame" ng-bind-html="eventItem.urlHTML" style="width:100%;height:100%;"> </iframe>
```

And what renders to the page is:

```
<iframe id="eventFrame" ng-bind-html="eventItem.urlHTML" style="width:100%;height:100%;" class="ng-binding">
   #document
      <html>
         <head></head>
         <body></body>
      </html>

   // HERE IS WHERE IMPORTED HTML IS ATTACHED:
   //
   // <!DOCTYPE html>, <HTML> and <BODY> tags are stripped
   //    ...but they are in the raw response, visible in the chrome dev tools network session
   //
   // All the below html is NOT a child of #document either, its at the same level.
   <meta ...>
   <link ...>
   <script> ...</script>
   <main>
     .... all the page code
   <main>

</iframe>
```

How can I properly attach the loaded HTML document to my iframe?